# Choosing data structure/storage solution for complex geo queries

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, redis, geolocation, postgis

I have a dataset of entities with their type and lat/long. Like this:

```
Name    Type Lat Long
House1  Big   1   2
House11  Bigger   2   2
House12  Biggest   3   2
House13  Small   4   2
House14  Medium 5   2
```

So these are houses with their type and location. Now I need to answer queries like: "Find all house of type Big which have a Small and a Medium house in its 10km radius"

What kind of data structure/storage solution would be right here? I looked at [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geoloc.html) and [Redis](https://redis.io/commands#geo) but looks like I need to iterate over all the houses of the given type (Big for the sample query above) to answer this.

Comment: Do you need to update/delete data or only add? How much queries do you expect? Do you really need to query all your dataset, or you will be looking in some area?

Comment: @Imaskar mostly add but update/delete is required. Queries will grow over time but for now 10-20 Queries per second. I need to query the entire dataset not some  specific area. But I am eager to listen to what you have in mind even with all the constraints.

Comment: Has anyone used http://tile38.com/ or https://github.com/tidwall/redis-gis?

Comment: note that it is limited by your RAM size

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly feasible directly from `PostgreSQL` with `PostGIS`.

Considering your table structure ...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (name TEXT, type TEXT, geom GEOGRAPHY);
```

... and your test data ...

```
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('House1','Big', ST_MakePoint(1,2));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('House11','Bigger', ST_MakePoint(2,2));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('House12','Biggest', ST_MakePoint(3,2));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('House13','Small', ST_MakePoint(4,2));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('House14','Medium', ST_MakePoint(5,2));
```

(Note: here makes no sense to split lat,long in different columns. PostGIS can store both in a single [`GEOGRAPHY`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/geography.html) or [`GEOMETRY`](https://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html) column. See [`ST_MakePoint`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) for more details.)

> "Find all house of type Big which have a Small and a Medium house in
>   its 10km radius"

Try something like this using [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html):

```
WITH j AS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE type = 'Big')
SELECT 
  j.name,j.type, 
  ST_Distance(j.geom,t.geom) AS distance, 
  t.name, t.type
FROM j,t 
WHERE 
  ST_Distance(j.geom,t.geom) > 10000 AND
  t.type IN ('Small','Medium');


  name  | type |    distance     |  name   |  type  
--------+------+-----------------+---------+--------
 House1 | Big  |  333756.3481116 | House13 | Small
 House1 | Big  | 445008.41595616 | House14 | Medium
(2 Zeilen)
```

(This query returns records which are more than 10k meters away from the `Big` type house. Just adapt the first where statement to your needs)

**EDIT:** Query based on the comments.

```
WITH j AS (SELECT *, ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT t2.type 
               FROM t t2
                   WHERE t2.type IN ('Small','Medium') AND 
               ST_Distance(t2.geom,t1.geom) < 100000
                   ) AS nearHouseType 
       FROM t t1 WHERE type = 'Big')
SELECT *
FROM j
WHERE j.nearHouseType @> '{Medium, Small}'::TEXT[]
```

Comment: 2 questions. 1. How well will it scale? I would easily have around 1 million entries. 2. I think this query will return the houses which have (Small or Medium) in the radius rather than (Small and Medium).

Comment: It'll scale pretty well if your table is properly indexed. You're right in your assumption, it's an OR conditional. Just change it for AND, then it'll be fine for you. Need help to adapt it?

Comment: Yes please if you could adapt it, it would be great!

Comment: Maybe it's my bad expirience with postgres talks, but how could it scale? N*N loop that can't be sharded? Add postgres's "super effectiveness" when it iterates an index and does 8kb random read for each row it found. On the other hand, 1m entries is not that much and a good server will do it.

Comment: @dharm0us I just added another query, which might be what you're looking for. Can you test it? Hard to know if it works well without proper sample data. Do not forget to index at least the columns `geom` and `type`

Comment: @JimJones thanks, will test it. Need to install Postgres first.

Comment: @dharm0us I see. You might wanna check this page to install postgis, in case you're still not familiar with it: https://postgis.net/install/